# Internet Explorer 9 and border-collapse

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Is there any way to fix the `border-collapse` problem in Internet Explorer 9?
When creating table with `border-collapse:collapse;` and td `position` set to `relative` - in some (most) cases some (most) borders are not being displayed at all...

Answer (score -2):

Use this CSS

```
table {
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: This does not collapse borders... all internal borders are doubled.

Comment: how do a avoid this issue with the left turn signal in my car not working? "Just turn right!". Very helpful.